# Stop media player on press of back button

Tags: java, android, media-player

I have a media player which plays mp3 from an URL. When I play a song and press the back button, the application gives an error. I used `prepareAsync();`.

I am new, so sorry if you cannot understand me well.

Here is my `play` function and `ondestroy` function. Thanks.

```
public void  playSong(final int naatindex){
    // Play song
    tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.mywidget);  
    try {
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(naatpaths[naatindex]);
        Log.w("Play Song", "CS"+naatindex);
        tv.setText("Buffering Please Wait....!");
        songCurrentDurationLabel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        tv.setSelected(true);
        songTotalDurationLabel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mp.prepareAsync();
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp){
                songCurrentDurationLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                songTotalDurationLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    mp.start();

                    tv.setText(naattitles[naatindex]);
                    // Changing Button Image to pause image
                    btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
                    // set Progress bar values
                    songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                    songProgressBar.setMax(100);
                    // Updating progress bar
                    updateProgressBar();
            }
        });



        mp.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                Log.w("Unable to Play", "CS"+naatindex);
                playSong(currentSongIndex+1);
                return false;
            }
        });




         // Set focus to the textview
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

  @Override
  public void onDestroy(){
  mp.release();
  mp = null;
  super.onDestroy();
  }
```

here is my log error

```
01-10 16:16:40.339: W/dalvikvm(26539): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416282a0)
01-10 16:16:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(26539): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-10 16:16:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(26539): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-10 16:16:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(26539):    at com.maulantariqjameel.bayyan.media_player$1.run(media_player.java:5032)
01-10 16:16:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(26539):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-10 16:16:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(26539):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-10 16:16:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(26539):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-10 16:16:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(26539):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
01-10 16:16:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(26539):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 16:16:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(26539):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-10 16:16:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(26539):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
01-10 16:16:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(26539):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
01-10 16:16:40.344: E/AndroidRuntime(26539):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override 
protected void onDestroy() { 
if (runnableObject != null) 
myHandler.removeCallbacks(runnableObject ); 
super.onDestroy(); 
}
private void backPressed() {
if (mpAudioSdCard != null) {
            mpAudioSdCard.stop();
            mpAudioSdCard.release();
            mpAudioSdCard = null;
        }

}
```

try this it will work for me  i think ur mistake is ur call   super.onDestroy();  first

Answer (score 2):

```
private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    if (mp!= null) {
        if(mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.stop();
        }
        mp.release();
        mp= null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    releaseMediaPlayer();
}
```

**OR**

```
private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    if (mp!= null) {
        if(mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.stop();
        }
        mp.release();
        mp= null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    releaseMediaPlayer();
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Friend i try this but still it give error can i send you log details

Answer (score 0):

In onDestroy() there is no need to call this.finish() as the activity is already being finished. Remove that line and try again.

Comment: Yes friend i remove this.finish() but still it give error. on closing app

Comment: If you could post the exact stack-trace of the error I will be able to help you better.

Comment: Zohaib I think there should be more stack-trace. I think you have posted only a part of it. Please post the entire stack-trace.

Answer (score 0):

You should call super.onbackpressed() before release..try this code

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
 super.onBackPressed();
System.out.println("onBackPressed() called");
releaseMediaPlayer();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the logs, it appears that the error is happening inside a `Runnable` that you have posted to a `Handler`. I'm guessing that you posted it using postDelayed() to update the UI or something based on the `MediaPlayer` state at a regular interval. Am I right? You are setting mp to null in the onDestroy() but the `Runnable` keeps running and tries to access it, causing the `NullPointerException`.

To fix this, you need to clear the handler's queue of pending Runnables in your onDestroy(), like this:

```
mHandler.removeCallbacks(null);
```

Even better is to do it in your onPause() and then restart it in onResume()